# how changing the output of angular2 ngModel through ControlValueAcessor

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I want to write a very simple Angular2 component which basically takes `ngControl` and `ngModel` from parent view. The input from parent is a `Date` and inside of the component I convert it to `String`. As output I want to bind the `String` back to `Date`.

```
const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => PtDatepicker),
        multi: true
    });

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "pt-datepicker",
    template: `<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="value">`,
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class PtDatepicker implements ControlValueAccessor {

    //The internal data model
    private _value:string = '';

    //Placeholders for the callbacks
    private _onTouchedCallback:() => void = noop;
    private _onChangeCallback:(_:any) => void = noop;

    //get accessor
    get value():any {
        return this._value;
    };

    //set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v:any) {
        if (v !== this._value) {
            this._value = v;
            this._onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value:Date) {
        const str = value ? moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : "";
        this._value = str;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn:any) {
        this._onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    //From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn:any) {
        this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
}
```

Call like this:

`<pt-datepicker [ngModel]="plan.validUntil" ngControl="validUntil"></pt-datepicker>`

I'm new to Angular2. Thanks for help! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the following to have two-way binding:

```
<pt-datepicker [(ngModel)]="plan.validUntil"
        ngControl="validUntil"></pt-datepicker>
```